# Getting Bounding Box of Caret in an editable WebView

Tags: cocoa, webkit

For a word processor I am writing I need to know sometimes the caret coordinates (the reason is long and uninteresting for the question itself). I writing the app. in Objective-C. I don't want to make calls to JavaScript and I don't want to make "tricks" like altering the DOM to get the caret coordinates (one solution would be to insert an empty span at the caret position and measure it bounding box). I've searched for methods that get the selected domrange bounding box with no success.

The only thing I found was a caretRectAtNode:offset:affinity in WebCoreFrameBridge (and other methods that seem to do what I want). So I see basically two answers to my question

1) There is a *magic* method in WebView that I am not considering

2) Tell me how to call methods inside WebCoreFrameBridge using Obj-C, and having a reference to a WebView/Frame/etc.

Comment: What's the magic method?

Comment: I don't know. "Maybe" there is a magic method. Sorry for my english and redaction.